# Greatest possible number of vertices in undirected graph of $|E|$ edges...

Tags: graph-theory

> Find the greatest possible number of vertices in an undirected graph of $|E| = 19$
>   edges, assuming the degree of each v $\in V$ is at least $3\ $

This looks like a problem which should take less than $5 \dots 10$ minutes to solve. What is the insight needed to solve this quickly?

Here are several lines of thought which didn't lead me anywhere

- Modify the problem and assume the degree of $v \in V$ is at least $1$.
- Try a smaller graph with $6$ edges.
- Apply the following ?

> **Theorem** : In any graph, the sum of the degrees of all vertices is equal to twice the number of edges.
>   
>   What obvious insight have I missed? Any hints or suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint 1: Use the theorem you stated to get an upper bound on the number of vertices.

> $$38 = 2|E| = \sum_v \operatorname{deg}(v) \ge 3 |V| \implies 12 \ge |V|.$$

Hint 2: Then, show that the upper bound can be attained.

> To show that there exists such a graph with 12 vertices, consider three copies of $K_4$ (the [complete graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph#Examples) with four vertices) and add one more edge.